# How do I overcome a syntax error in jBase when using =>

Tags: jbase

I have a program that uses a logical expression, e.g., C = (A => B), however when I try to compile it using BASIC, I get the following error:

```
0001 A = 1
0002 B = 2
0003 C = (A => B)


"TEST", 3 (offset 10)  near RESERVED WORD "GT":
C = (A = GT  B)
         ^
        syntax error

1 error was found
jbccom -f -d -aBPX BASIC_91.b failed , command returned a code of 1
jcompile: Returned an error code of 8
 ** Unable to compile source TEST **
```

I have the same program on a different server running the exact same environment, i.e., same Linux version, same Red Hat version, same jBase version and this code compiles with no issue.

Is there an environment variable or config item that is different from one server to another?

jDiag Output:

```
            jdiag - jBASE diagnostic '$Revision: 1.15 $'

System Information
==================

System                      : Linux INT-PWS 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64.#1 SMP Fri Aug 10 16:55:11 UTC 2018 x86_64
OS Release                  : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
UNIX User                   : ch2bri (uid 1013, euid 1013)
Tty name                    : /dev/pts/23
jBASE User (JBCLOGNAME)     : CH2BRI
Time                        : Tue Sep 21 10:33:37 2021

Environment
===========

JBCPORTNO                   : Not Set
JBCRELEASEDIR               : '/home/pw/library5631'
JBCGLOBALDIR                : '/home/pw/library5631'
JBCDATADIR                  : '/home/pw/jbase_data'
HOME                        : '/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI'
JEDIFILEPATH                : '/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI'
JEDIFILENAME_MD             : '/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI_HOME/MD]D'
JEDIFILENAME_SYSTEM         : '/home/pw/SYSTEM]D'
RELEASE Information         : Major 5.6 , Minor 3.1 , Patch 0677 (Change 20365)
Spooler dir (JBCSPOOLERDIR) : '/home/pw/jspooler'
Spooler directory '/home/pw/jspooler' OK
JBCEMULATE                  : 'universe'
Emulation Config file '/home/pw/library5631/config/Config_EMULATE' OK
JBCEMULATE Label 'universe' found in file '/home/pw/library5631/config/Config_EMULATE'

Executable search Path: /home/pw/scripts:/opt/ActivePerl-5.26/bin:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/bin:.:/home/pw/library5631/bin:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/bin:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
WARNING: Your execute path (PATH) does not contain '/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI/bin'
Shared Object search path: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/lib:/home/pw/library5631/lib:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/bin:/usr/local/libexec:/usr/lib

   Found                    : '/home/pw/library5631/lib/libjbase.so'
   Found                    : '/home/pw/library5631/lib/libjbaseutil.so'
   Found                    : '/home/pw/library5631/lib/libjsub.so'
Object path (JBCOBJECTLIST) : '/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/lib:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/lib:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/WMShcAPI/lib'
WARNING: Cannot access Object path '/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/WMShcAPI/lib', error 2
jBASE Compiler Run-time     : '/home/pw/library5631/config/system.properties'
Program dir (JBCDEV_BIN)    : '/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/bin'
Program Path '/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/bin' is in your PATH
Subroutine dir (JBCDEV_LIB) : '/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/lib'
Subroutine path '/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/lib' is in JBCOBJECTLIST
Max open files              : 4096

Full Environment
================

        SHELL=/home/pw/library5631/bin/jsh
        _=jdiag
        TERM=vt220
        JBCTERM=vt220
        CBOLD=
        CC=gcc
        CDPATH=.:/home/pw:/home:/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI
        CHILI=
        CLASSPATH=/home/pw/library5631/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar
        CNORM=
        CREV=
        EM_TRACELOGS=/home/pw/tmp
        EM_TRACELVL=0x3fdf
        ENV=/home/pw/scripts/.env
        HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
        HISTSIZE=1000
        HOME=/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI
        HOSTNAME=INT-PWS
        JBASE_LOCALE=en_US
        JBASE_SVR_SESSION=1
        JBCBASETMP=/home/pw/WORKFILES/57988
        JBCDATADIR=/home/pw/jbase_data
        JBCDEV_BIN=/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/bin
        JBCDEV_LIB=/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/lib
        JBCEMULATE=universe
        JBCGLOBALDIR=/home/pw/library5631
        JBCLOGNAME=CH2BRI
        JBCNETACCESS=/home/pw/library5631/config
        JBCNETDIR=/home/pw/library5631/config
        JBCOBJECTLIST=/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/lib:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/lib:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/WMShcAPI/lib
        JBCRELEASEDIR=/home/pw/library5631
        JBCSPOOLERDIR=/home/pw/jspooler
        JBC_ONLINECATALOG=1
        JBC_STDERR=1
        JEDIENABLEQ2Q=1
        JEDIFILENAME_MD=/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI_HOME/MD]D
        JEDIFILENAME_SYSTEM=/home/pw/SYSTEM]D
        JEDIFILEPATH=/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI
        JREDIR=/home/pw/library5631/jdk/jre
        JRELIB=/home/pw/library5631/jdk/jrelib:/home/pw/library5631/jdk/jvmlib
        JRFS_LOCALPATH_JQL=1
        JRFS_REMOTE_JQL=1
        LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
        LDR_CNTRL=PREREAD_SHLIB
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/lib:/home/pw/library5631/lib:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/bin:/usr/local/libexec:/usr/lib
        LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
        LIBPATH=/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/lib:/home/pw/library5631/lib:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/bin:/usr/local/libexec:/usr/lib
        LOGNAME=ch2bri
        LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
        MAIL=/var/spool/mail/ch2bri
        MAILSENDMINUSR=qa_demo-ch2bri@paperlesswarehousing.com.au
        MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/local/man
        PATH=/home/pw/scripts:/opt/ActivePerl-5.26/bin:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/bin:.:/home/pw/library5631/bin:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/bin:/home/pw/PROD/SOURCE/plugins/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
        PS1=$USER@INT-PWS:$PWD>
        PWD=/home/pw/PROD/CH2BRI
        PWHOME=/home/pw
        PWMAINACCT=
        QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED=1
        SHLVL=1
        SSH_CLIENT=172.17.18.35 52444 22
        SSH_CONNECTION=172.17.18.35 52444 192.9.200.206 22
        SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/23
        TZ=Australia/Brisbane
        USER=ch2bri
        XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1013
        XDG_SESSION_ID=331341
        Z_DISABLE_QUEUEING=1
        A__z="*SHLVL
        JBCLKFILE=/home/pw/library5631/tmp/LOCKFILE
        JBCPAUSEFILE=/home/pw/library5631/tmp/PAUSEFILE
        JBCERRFILE=/home/pw/library5631/jbcmessages
        JBASE_DATABASE=default
```

Comment: Not familiar with jbase at all, but if you want to do a comparison for "greater or equal", all languages I know use `>=`, and not `=>`.

Comment: Can you run a jdiag and post what version of jBASE this is? I ran this code on a clean install of 5.8.2, as an example, and it compiled with no issue.

Comment: @MikeWright see jDiag output added to the question.

Comment: I would also say that "=GT" does not look good, and as best practice you should write A = (B >= C)

Answer (score 1):

The issue revolves around the version of jBase. These issues with the jBase pre-compiler have been addressed in later versions of jBase 5.7 and above.

Upgrading the jBase version corrected the issue.